# Search / Filter in List of Elements with Sublists

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I am not extremely familiar with JS and want to filter a list of elements by a given string.
This website shows an example of what I want to achieve:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp

In addition to this functionality, I want to be able to filter the list based on sublists.
So say I have a main list like this one:

```
<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li id="tt"><a href="#">Agnes</a>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cake</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
```

and I type in "Agnes" in the search bar; then I want the "Agnes"-element to appear with all of its children shown. If I search for "Test", I want to show the "Agnes"-element as well as the "Test"-element.
If possible, I do not want to show the other children of "Agnes" (so f.e. Cake) or (even better) I want to show all of the children, but mark the one that has been found in a color. So the end result would look something like this:

[Filtered list with the found entry marked in green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncPq7.png)

I tried modifying the code on the website as following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li id="tt"><a href="#">Agnes</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Cake</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        children = li[i].getElementsByTagName("li");
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        txtValuesChildren = new Array()
        for (j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
            child=children[j].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
            txtValueC = child.textContent || child.innerText;
            txtValuesChildren.push(txtValueC);
            }
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) <= -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "";
            for (j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
                children[j].style.display = "none";}
            
        }
        for (j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
            txtValue = txtValuesChildren[j]
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) <= -1) {
            children[j].style.background = "white";
            
        } else {
            children[j].style.display = "";
            children[j].style.background = "green";
            children[j].parentNode.style.display = "";
            
        }
        }
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So basically I tried to iterate through every child element in a given list element and look if the given search text matched there. However, this does not result in the outcome I want, because child elements are not shown if I search for them (or their parents). What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fiddle might be close to something you are after: https://jsfiddle.net/mszvnx84/1/

To achieve this, I create a flattened structure representing the DOM hierarchy (your nested `<ul>`/`<li>` lists), then when the input value changes I do the following:

- Remove any existing "matched" styles.
- Filtering the flattened structure to match against the values (the text content of the `<a>` tags).
- Apply a "matched" style to elements that match the value.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!
Is there a way I can hide every entry that does not match the searched term?

Comment: Sure, I updated the fiddle to apply hidden styles to all elements and selectively show only the ones whose value or parent values match the search term: https://jsfiddle.net/y2fL3v7z/5/

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to modify your solution and now it shows every element of a list if one element in that list is found ( see here: https://jsfiddle.net/borisgiba/n32jdb7m/1/ ), so now it works exactly as I wanted it. If I can somehow return the favor, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

In html put an id to every li item you want to get into an array in javascript, and then in javascript make that array with document.querySelectorAll('id name'). Technicly will be a nodeList at first but you can make an array with Array.from(nodeList);